# I want to upgrade all npm packages in node-loopback application

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, strongloop, loopback

I have a node application, with installed all node packages compatible to node version 0.10.25,

But now I have to upgrade all the packages compatible to current node version i.e. node version 10.15.3

I've tried two ways till now i.e.

1.) npm upgrade --save

2.) hardcoded packages updated version in package.json file, and then run.

```
npm install --save
```

But I've ended Up with error like

```
Error: Cannot resolve path "loopback/server/middleware/compress"
```

After above error I tried

```
npm install compress --save
```

after that also Same error.

My previous package.json file looks like

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "email-templates": "^1.2.1",
    "errorhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "loopback": "^2.8.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.4.0",
    "loopback-component-storage": "^1.5.0",
    "loopback-connector-mysql": "^2.1.1",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.7.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^1.3.4",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^1.0.3",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "strongloop": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "loopback-explorer": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.5.6"
  },
...
```

My current package.json file looks like below (Mannually find updated version of all packages from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ )

```
 ...
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "email-templates": "^5.0.4",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "loopback": "^3.25.1",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.28.0",
    "loopback-component-storage": "^3.6.0",
    "loopback-connector-mysql": "^5.3.1",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^4.6.2",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.0",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "strongloop": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.10.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "description": "orders"
}
...
```

I have to extent The application which meet the business logic For that I need to install very many new packages but not available / compatible with my current packages ,

Any reference or advice for doing so would be really helpful for me.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are upgrading many dependencies to a higher semver-major version, you need to deal with breaking changes introduced in those versions.

LoopBack provides a migration guide for developers upgrading from 2.x to 3.x, see https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Migrating-to-3.0.html.

> `Error: Cannot resolve path "loopback/server/middleware/compress"`

LoopBack 3.x upgraded Express from 2.x to 3.x (IIRC) and as a result, popular middleware is no longer bundled - applications have to install and load them explicitly.

I see that you already have `compression` listed in your dependencies, so now you need to change the code calling `require('loopback/server/middleware/compress')` to call `require(compression')` instead. Check also your `server/middleware.json` file, LoopBack applications usually configure middleware through that config file.

> `"loopback-datasource-juggler": "^4.6.2",`

In LoopBack 3.0, we moved `loopback-datasource-juggler` from `peerDependencies` to regular `dependencies`, LoopBack applications are no longer depending on juggler directly. Please remove this entry from your `package.json`.

See https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Migrating-to-3.0.html#edit-packagejson and https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/3.0-Release-Notes.html#loopback-datasource-juggler-is-now-a-regular-dependency-of-loopback

Comment: Thank you for your great response It may work for me, Let me check that once, I'll update you after giving this a try. :-)